# avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT with google maps using setTimeout, unexpected time gaps

Tags: javascript, settimeout, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to avoid the dreaded over query limit messages from the google geocode api.

I'm getting my data in batches of 10 from the server. Within one batch the timings are good, but between batches there is a growing delay that I don't understand. I've checked the timing on getting new records but that is subsecond and not the issue.

I'm looking for some guidance on where the gaps are created (and ideally how they can be removed).
The exact code is below. I basically use a counter that is steady over the different batches, and I use a setTimeout with a timing of `(300*counter)` to make sure that they don't fire all at the same time. Which again works nicely within a batch, but not over batches.

The timings between the different batches is:

```
start batch 1 :"2013-03-26 15:40:15.882337"
stop batch  1 :"2013-03-26 15:40:18.586881"
start batch 2 :"2013-03-26 15:40:21.688363" (3 seconds between batches)
stop batch  2 :"2013-03-26 15:40:24.384641"
start batch 3 :"2013-03-26 15:40:30.449829" (6 seconds between batches)
stop batch  3 :"2013-03-26 15:40:33.150393"
start batch 4 :"2013-03-26 15:40:42.216579" (9 seconds between batches)
stop batch  4 :"2013-03-26 15:40:44.917545"
start batch 5 :"2013-03-26 15:40:56.991258" (12 seconds between batches)
stop batch  5 :"2013-03-26 15:40:59.689068"
start batch 6 :"2013-03-26 15:41:14.742534" (15 seconds between batches)
stop batch  6 :"2013-03-26 15:41:17.444024"
start batch 7 :"2013-03-26 15:41:35.500424" (18 seconds between batches)
```

As you can see the gaps between the batches is growing.

The code I use:

```
  getRecords: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

    var self = this;
    var recordsDone = 0;

    if (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.geocode.length; i++) {

        // build the address string
        var addressQuery = this.buildAddress(data, i);

        setTimeout(function(addr, recId) {
          self.googleGeocoder.geocode({'address': addr}, function(result, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
              $.ajax({
                url: '/geocode/' + recId + '.json',
                data: {'status': status, 'lat': result[0].geometry.location.kb, 'long': result[0].geometry.location.lb},
                type: 'PUT',
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                  var total = parseFloat(data.total);
                  var done = parseFloat(data.done);
                  self.set('voortgang', (done/total)*100);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
              });
            } else {
              $.ajax({
                url: '/geocode/' + recId + '.json',
                data: {'status': status},
                type: 'PUT',
                success: function(datra, textStatus, xhr) {
                  var total = parseFloat(data.total);
                  var done = parseFloat(data.done);
                  self.set('voortgang', (done/total)*100);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
              });
            }

            recordsDone++;

            if (recordsDone === data.geocode.length) {
              console.log('about to get records ' + new Date().toUTCString());
              $.ajax({
                url: '/geocode.json',
                data: {data_set_id: self.datasetid},
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                  console.log('got the records ' + new Date().toUTCString());
                  self.getRecords(data, textStatus, xhr);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  // set to fully geocoded
                  var found = self.get('content').findProperty('id', self.datasetid);
                  Ember.set(found, 'data_set.fully_geocoded', true);
                  self.set(voortgang, 0);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }, (300*this.globalRecordsDone), addressQuery, data.geocode[i].id);

        // another record has been handled
        this.globalRecordsDone++;
      }
    }

    // get records the first time
    if (this.firstTime === true) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/geocode.json',
        data: {data_set_id: this.datasetid},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
          self.getRecords(data, textStatus, xhr);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('stop getting records');
        }
      });

      this.firstTime = false;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be on this line:

`}, (300*this.globalRecordsDone), addressQuery, data.geocode[i].id);`

I think that you just want:

`}, (300), addressQuery, data.geocode[i].id);`

You are increasing the amount of time that `setTimeout` waits.  The first batch, it is waiting  for 300 mil between requests, the second round 600 mils, the third round 900 mils, etc.  This is why you are getting 3 seconds ( 300 mils times ten records = 3 seconds.), then 6 seconds, 600 mils times 10 records = 6 seconds.)

Comment: I'm increasing the globalRecordsDone after each call, each record. If I don't do that all 10 requests will fire at the same time, with a delay of 300ms from when the loop started. If I remove the * globalRecordsDone allmost every record has a over_query_limit response.

Answer (score 0):

I made the timing a function of the loop, and I had to increase the timeout to 1200 in order to get through a dataset without the over query limit.
I think I stayed within the query limit before due to the minumum break of 3 seconds between batches. The process is now fluent without any obvious breaks.

So instead of

```
}, (300*this.globalRecordsDone), addressQuery, data.geocode[i].id);
```

it became

```
}, (1200*i), addressQuery, data.geocode[i].id);
```